# What is the formula for multiplication of two finite power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

What is formula for multiplication of two finite power series?
$$\sum_{i=0}^m {m \choose i}x^i   \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}x^j$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The finite series are just polynomials, so you multiply them as such. More generally, the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two formal power series is obtained by multiplying them as if they were polynomials. Thus, the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}b_kx^k\right)$$

is $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;.$$

In your problem, if

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kx^k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}c_kx^k\;,$$

then $$c_k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{m}i\binom{n}{k-i}=\binom{m+n}k\;.$$

**Added:** That last step uses [Vandermonde’s identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), which is easily proved either from the binomial theorem, as in lab bhattacharjee’s answer, or by a purely combinatorial argument.

Comment: In this particular example $a_k$ makes sense when $k>m$ but what if $a_k$ were not defined when $k>m$ (similarly for $b_{k-i}$ when $k-i>n$)?

Comment: Can this be generalized to multivariate case? In other word, can a formula for the multiplication of two multinomial expansion be given?

Answer (score 10):

Using well known [Binomial Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html), $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$ for natural $n,$

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k}x^k  \right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k\right)=(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}=\sum_{r=0}^{m+n} {{m+n} \choose r}x^r$$