# Product of a Multinomial done using Multinomial Theorem?

Tags: summation, cauchy-product, multinomial-theorem

I was looking into the multinomial theorem to try to understand more about summing a sequence over a composition of a number with non-negative elements (a weak composition). In particular, I am curious about multiplying two of the same multinomial sums and  combine the summations somehow into a single term such as the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). 
$$
(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m)^a (x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m)^b = \left(\sum_{\pi_m \in C_a} {a \choose \pi_a} \prod_{v=1}^m x_m^{\lambda_m}\right)\left(\sum_{\pi_m \in C_b} {b \choose \pi_a} \prod_{v=1}^m x_m^{\lambda_m}\right)
$$
I intuitively do not understand how multiplying a sum over a weak composition would work. I realized this can easily be solved using algebra or other trivial methods, but I am looking to understand how this method would work to create the solution.

Comment: Multiplying in summation notation is easy. Just multiply the general summand terms and make it a double sum. After that you use a combinatorial argument.

Comment: @MattSamuel Could you give me an example with the combinatorial argument? For example like $a=q-b$ and $b=b$ just as an example and how that would work.

Comment: You would be proving that $\sum_{\pi_a+\pi_b=\pi_q}{\binom{a}{\pi_a}\binom{b}{\pi_b}}=\binom{q}{\pi_q}$, where $\pi_q$ is fixed. It's too far past my bed time for me to work it out, but I'm 100% certain this has a nice combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: @MattSamuel I am very interested in understanding more, would you happen to have any references of any kind?

Comment: there are symmetric functions and hall polynomials by Macdonald, and enumerative combinatorics by Stanley, but those are both graduate level.

Comment: @MattSamuel I don't mind a difficult read as long as it captures my interest, and enumerative combinatorics is very interesting so far. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: It would be very nice if someone can add an answer to the question; I'm also looking at the same problem which will be a generalization of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272841/what-is-formula-for-multiple-two-finite-series